# match first x characters of a word or the rest of the word with regex

Tags: regex

I have two words `a` and `b`. I need to know if the first x characters--say x = 3--of `a` match the first x characters of `b` but, if the `a` is longer than x characters, then the subsequent characters of `a` must match the corresponding characters in `b`.

Let me explain with an example. Say `a` is "Col", `b` is "Colombia" and x = 3. Given that the first 3 characters of `a` match the first 3 in `b`, then its `TRUE`. If `a` were "Colo" or "Colom", the regex should return TRUE as well because these cases match `b`. However, if `a` were "Coll" or "Colum", it would be FALSE.

I come up with two solutions, but none seem to work perfectly.

1. `(a, "^Col(o|ol|olo|olom|olomb|olombi|olombia)")`
2. `("Colombia", ^a)`

The first solution meets all the conditions, but it is extremely **tedious** to write, especially if you have many words to match. The second case is easier to write, but it will match "C" or "Co", and I need to match minimum the first 3 (or x).

Is there a way to write a regex that does what I need?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems like, for the same `a` & `b`, the result of your regex should be the same no matter what `x` is.

Comment: HI @ScottHunter, I apologize for not being clear. Notice that, in my first attempt, a matched "Col" or "Colo" but not "Co", because x is equal to 3. Of course, I don't have x explicitly defined here, but that idea of having a minimum number of characters to match remains. Thanks

Comment: Why does this need to be a regex?  In what context will it be used?

Comment: How about [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/zoAJNK/2), do these examples match accordingly?

Comment: Hello @R.AndresCastaneda, I solve it using `bash` and a regex but with an inline `if` statement to determine the last character to check, `X` will be the user argument or the length of the `B` argument if `len(B)` is greater than `X`, do you will be agree with the solution or do you need explicitly just a regex expression?

Answer (score 3):

In the general form this is what you're describing :

`(\b\w{3,}\b).*?\b\1`

https://regex101.com/r/x1Z4mg/1

Explanation :

```
 (                   # (1 start)
    \b                  # word boundary
    \w{3,}              # 3 or more word chars
    \b                  # word boundary
 )                   # (1 end)
 .*? 
 \b                  # word boundary
 \1                  # back reference to capture 1
```

This can be expanded to not span lines, lookahead for the second word, etc.
Or to change the *words* to be a mix of literals as well.
Depends on what's needed.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... Say `a` is "Col", `b` is "Colombia" and x = 3. Given that the first 3 characters of `a` match the first 3 in `b`, then its `TRUE`. ..."*

This could be matched by

```
^Col.*
```

> *"... If `a` were "Colo" or "Colom", the regex should return TRUE as well because these cases match `b` ..."*

Similarly, the patterns would be

```
^Colo.*
^Colom.*
```

> *"... However, if `a` were "Coll" or "Colum", it would be FALSE."*

Again, the same pattern.

```
^Coll.*
^Colum.*
```

I believe you're looking to just utilize the ^ meta-character.
This will cause the pattern to be matched starting at the first character in the value—also referred to as, the start-of-string.